# Why am I getting a buffer overrun error with this line of code?

Tags: destructor, pcre, buffer-overrun

I only have 1 line of code, and this is:

```
pcrecpp::RE re("abc");
```

inside a function `OnBnClickedButtonGo()`. And this function fails in Release mode, but it works OK in debug mode.

(I am using Visual Studio 8 on Windows XP.)

The error message is:

```
A buffer overrun has occurred in testregex.exe which has corrupted the program's
internal state. Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate
the program.
For more details please see Help topic 'How to debug Buffer Overrun Issues'.
```

I suspect it is its destructor, which is invisible and implied... but I don't know really.

PS: I am statically linking to the PCRE lib version 7.8.
PS2: Not very relevant, but may help some people who have trouble linking to the PCRE library (it took me hours to sort it out): include the line `#define PCRE_STATIC`.

Comment: Did you build the library, or was it a canned lib?  Either way, was it compiled with the same compiler?  If not, I'd try building the lib with your compiler and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message in my case. In debug is everything fine, but in release I get the error message. I have a native C/C++ library like `native.dll`. I have created a mixed unmanaged/managed C++ library, which is a wrapper for that library to .net. Somewhere in this `mixed.dll` I have an unmanaged function signature declaration, like:

```
typedef void ( *FunctionOnStartSend)();
```

for this the I get the message, but if I add a "magic word" there then there is no error message:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *FunctionOnStartSend)();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's happening only in release mode, it's possible that something is getting "optimized" out. Try doing something more than just the one liner, like a Match() and maybe even printing out the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fresh history:
About a month ago I've got a strange link failure of the VS2008 and that day I dug that setting **_SECURE_SCL=0** may help (see [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)). And it helped. That day it helped me and I just propagated this setting to all the libs we build at team -- that's because MS says that two libs built with different _SECURE_SCL are incompartible.

Time passed and three days ago I've got a bug when VS2008 says that error message that we see in the first post. And there are no help from the debugger because it overruns only in Release build. I've spend almost 2 days pump'n'jump'n the code of the libs and the overrun was flawed from line to line. Finally I started checking build settings line by line and figured the diff in this setting!

Why, oh why Microsoft guys can't embed some small check in dynamic loader code to test that the library currently running and the one going to be dynamically loaded are **incompartible**?! Some pice of code that save people's time. Blah!